# EpicEditor: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, epiceditor

I am trying to load 3 EpicEditor instances on the same page: http://jsbin.com/ripukati/1/edit?html,js.
The error I'm getting is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` 
Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: `of null` is referring to the element it gave. The selector you gave isn't returning any matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your jsbin your HTML id's are `epiceditor-...` and in the code the container id's are `editor-...`

After changing that it [worked well](http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/GDT5c/).